# How does R judges positive and negative factor variables?

Tags: r, classification, roc, gbm, h2o

I want to do a binary classification and one level is "top", the other is "bottom". I used gbm in h2o packages and get "bottom" as positive class and "top" as negative class. 
Here is my code:

```
fit <- h2o.gbm(x = regr.var, y = max.var,
             training_frame = ddd, 
             nfolds = 10, 
             distribution = 'multinomial',
             balance_classes = TRUE)
pred <- as.data.frame(h2o.predict(fit, newdata = eee))
threshold <- 0.5
pred1 <- factor( ifelse(pred[, 'top'] > threshold, 'top', 'bottom') )
err.res<-confusionMatrix(pred1 , hh$score_class)
err.res
```

Here is the result:

```
Confusion Matrix and Statistics
           Reference
Prediction bottom top
bottom      420   123
top          1     6
Accuracy : 0.7745          
95% CI : (0.7373, 0.8088)
No Information Rate : 0.7655          
P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.3279          

Kappa : 0.0657          
Mcnemar's Test P-Value : <2e-16          

Sensitivity : 0.99762         
Specificity : 0.04651         
Pos Pred Value : 0.77348         
Neg Pred Value : 0.85714         
Prevalence : 0.76545         
Detection Rate : 0.76364         
Detection Prevalence : 0.98727         
Balanced Accuracy : 0.52207         

'Positive' Class : bottom
```

But I want to correctly predict more "top". I tried to change the threshold to 0.3, and it performs better. However, should I change in the fitting process to make more prediction to "top" like "ROC" metric? Should I flip the "top" to positive class and "bottom" to negative class and how can I change it?

Comment: You have a case of class imbalance. If you want to correctly predict the smaller class (i.e. "top" in your example), you will have to modify your method to make correctly classifying the smaller class have more weight. This is not a programming question - you might find better responses on a different site like the [stats](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) or [cs](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) sites.

Comment: R does not have a concept of positive and negative factor variable. This is entirely handled by the h2o package so you should ask those people. Usually 0 and 1 are correctly understood by most third-party tools.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to add the 'positive' argument to your function:

```
err.res <- confusionMatrix(pred1, hh$score_class, positive="top")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using h2o.confustionMatrix and using that to create matrices at different threshold values.

Ex. `h2o.confusionMatrix(object = fit, threshold = 0.3)`

Thanks,

Avni

Answer (score 0):

If you want to declare a positive class directly in h2o, in order to have correct metrics (with `h2o.confusionMatrix`, `h2o.performance` etc.), you can use the function `h2o.relevel`. For instance in your example, you should add before the model training:

```
ddd[max.var] <- h2o.relevel(ddd[max.var],'bottom')
```

(by default, I believe h2o decides of the positive class based on alphabetic order, and in your exemple h2o metric functions should work right away)